# How to I get value from Select Option tag using JavaScript function

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, html5-canvas

I have a dropdown list like this:

```
<select id="itemsList" onchange="gettingList()">
    <option>Please select the option</option>
    <option value="50">Soap</option>
    <option value="100">Sugar</option>
    <option value="290">Oil</option>
</select>
<br><br>
```

I have to get the value of the above list in the below input tag.

```
<input type="text" id="price">
```

For this, I am using this script.

```
<script>
    function gettingList() {
        var selectItem = document.getElementById('itemsList').value;
        var displayPrice = selectItem.options[selectItem.selectedIndex].text;
        document.getElementById('price').value = displayPrice;
    }
</script>
```

How can I resolve this issue.?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```js
var selectItem = document.getElementById('itemsList');

function gettingList() {
  document.getElementById('price').value = selectItem.value;
}
```

```html
<select id="itemsList" onchange="gettingList()">
  <option>Please select the option</option>
  <option value="50">Soap</option>
  <option value="100">Sugar</option>
  <option value="290">Oil</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<input type="text" id="price">
```

Answer (score 0):

You get the selected price via the select `value` property. now, you can update the input with it.

```js
    function gettingList() {
    
        var selectItemPrice = document.getElementById('itemsList').value;
        document.getElementById('price').value = selectItemPrice;
    }
```

```html
<select id="itemsList" onchange="gettingList()">
    <option>Please select the option</option>
    <option value="50">Soap</option>
    <option value="100">Sugar</option>
    <option value="290">Oil</option>
</select>
<br><br>

<input type="text" id="price">
```

**More about the select element** - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be like this

```js
function gettingList() {
  let itemsList = document.querySelector('#itemsList');
  let price = itemsList.value
  let item = itemsList.options[itemsList.selectedIndex].text

  document.querySelector("#price").value = price
  document.querySelector("#item").value = item

  console.log(price, item)
}
```

```html
<select id="itemsList" onchange="gettingList()">
    <option>Please select the option</option>
    <option value="50">Soap</option>
    <option value="100">Sugar</option>
    <option value="290">Oil</option>
</select>

<input placeholder="Price" type="text" id="price">
<input placeholder="Item" type="text" id="item">
```